# Static method syntax confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods, static-methods

This is how we make static functions in Python:

```
class A:
   @staticmethod
   def fun():
      print 'hello'

A.fun()
```

This works as expected and prints `hello`.

If it is a member function instead of a static one, we use `self`:

```
class A:
   def fun(self):
      print 'hello'

A().fun()
```

which also works as expected and prints `hello`.

My confusion is with the following case:

```
class A:
   def fun():
      print 'hello'
```

In the above case, there is no `staticmethod`, nor `self`. Python interpreter is okay with this definition. However, we cannot call it either of the above methods, namely:

```
A.fun()
A().fun()
```

both gives errors.

**My question is:** Is there any way that I can call this function? If not, why Python do not give me a syntax error in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python doesn't give you a syntax error, because the binding of a method (which takes care of passing in `self`) is a *runtime* action.

Only when you look up a method on a class or instance, is a method being bound (because functions are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) they produce a method when looked up this way). This is done via the [`descriptor.__get__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__), which is called by the [`object.__getattribute__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__), which Python called when you tried to access the `fun` attribute on the `A` class or `A()` instance.

You can always 'unwrap' the bound method and reach for the un-wrapped function underneath to call it directly:

```
A.fun.__func__()
```

Incidentally, that's exactly what `staticmethod` does; it is there to 'intercept' the descriptor binding and return the raw function object instead of a bound method. In other words, `staticmethod` *undoes* the normal runtime method binding:

Demo:

```
>>> class A(object): pass
... 
>>> def fun(): print 'hello!'
... 
>>> fun.__get__(None, A)  # binding to a class
<unbound method A.fun>
>>> fun.__get__(None, A)()   # calling a bound function, fails as there is no first argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method fun() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>> fun.__get__(None, A).__func__  # access the wrapped function
<function fun at 0x100ba8378>
>>> staticmethod(fun).__get__(None, A)  # staticmethod object just returns the function
<function fun at 0x100ba8378>
>>> staticmethod(fun).__get__(None, A)()  # so calling it works
hello!
```